# How to focus for long hours?

Tags: motivation

I'm currently working on my A levels and would like to know about how to focus for longer hours and stay motivated? I'm also working on STEP Support program for entry into Cambridge and would like to know if there are certain tricks to be able to do maths faster.

Thanks

Comment: This is not really a math question. However: You either find motivation from within (that is "you like solving math problems") or without.

Comment: You shouldn't radically change the question by editing. Now you have something that at least appears to be math, but with a totally unrelated, yet accepted answer. Your original question was somewhat well-received, even though it was closed for being off topic. Just revert it and let it stay closed.

Comment: Ok sure I've kept the question as it was earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask myself the same question all of the time... It can either come intrinsically (you actually want to do the problem for some personal gain) or extrinsically (OH CRAP MY TEST IS TOMORROW!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!), but I would just focus on the fact that it needs to get done. It's not always fun, especially when you haven't even been taught the material or the solution seems to come out of nowhere, but you just gotta force yourself to do it. Have discipline. I majored in math and experience the same thing, but I dread doing things because it's usually confusing, and I know it will take forever, but then I remember, the test is coming up, and I can't fail the class, so I just make myself do it. Sometimes I'll call up a friend, and we'll work on the homework together so that I'm not just sitting there totall frustrated with Laurent series or something painful that the textbook is useless for.

Comment: Haha...true..I plan on majoring in math toooo and I see genuises working on advanced level stuff while I have doubts in A level maths

Comment: I love math, I just get frustrated when we're assigned problems that looking nothing like anything I've seen before, and I don't even know how to approach it without googling the shit out of it until hopefully I find something useful.

Comment: Yea I love math too..I'd like to specialise in number theory...I just imagine yitang Zhang working on big questions try think harder..that doesn't motivate but thinking harder works